# How can I unzip the zipped file using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to unzip the zipped file while downloading the file using AngularJS.

I am trying with the following code,

For eg:

```
<a download="My_File.PNG" target="_self" ng-href="Path of the zip file/My_File.PNG.zip">My_File.PNG</a>
```

How can I download the actual file `My_File.PNG` from `My_File.PNG.zip` in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it from angular directly, but you can call use the JSUnzip library which you can call from your angular controller https://github.com/augustl/js-unzip

```
     var myZip = ... // Get it with an XHR request, HTML5 files, etc.
     var unzipper = new JSUnzip(myZip);
     unzipper.isZipFile();      // true or false

     unzipper.readEntries();    // Creates "entries"
     unzipper.entries;          // Array of JSUnzip.ZipEntry objects.
```

Comment: not working , there is big problem while trying to open the file 
the error usually comes saying  `this.stream.charCodeAt is not a function
JSUnzip.BigEndianBinaryStream.prototype.getByteAt@../js/js-unzip.js:102`

js-unzip.js line 102

` getByteAt: function (index) {
            return this.stream.charCodeAt(index);
 //        return this.stream.charCodeAt(index) & 0xff;//patch i found off the net, that also not helpful
        }` .

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late, but the problem is in the angular request. You have to pass a special parameter, as in
$http.get('...', { responseType: "arraybuffer" }).success(successfunc);
and then proceed with the unzip. Search for this...